# What should I do for Python Fbchat Login error?

Tags: python, facebook

```
from fbchat import Client
fc = Client('______@gmail.com', '______')
```

I used this simple code from fbchat documentation, but when I tried logging in, I always get this error

```
Attempt #1 failed, retrying
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_client.py", line 205, in login
    self._state = State.login(
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_state.py", line 151, in login
    return cls.from_session(session=session)
  File "C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fbchat\_state.py", line 190, in from_session
    revision = int(r.text.split('"client_revision":', 1)[1].split(",", 1)[0])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What should I do?
My python version is 3.8

Comment: Facebook doesn't allow you to scrape them or bypass their API which fbchat is doing. Most likely Facebook changed something which broke fbchat.

Comment: Hmm, you mean...that we can't use fbchat anymore because facebook blocked that?

Comment: Facebook never allowed you to use fbchat. If it doesn't work you will have to talk to the people that made fbchat.

Answer (score 0):

in your pc go to the path:
C:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\fbchat_state.py

line 190, change:

```
revision = int(r.text.split('"client_revision":', 1)[1].split(",", 1)[0])
```

to:

```
revision = 1
```

Then save it and run your code again, it should work.

Comment: Would do best for the OP, for you to explain why you recommend a change of code.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
def session_factory(user_agent=None):
    session = requests.session()
    session.headers["Referer"] = "https://www.facebook.com"
    session.headers["Accept"] = "text/html"
    return session

fbchat._state.session_factory = session_factory
fbchat._state.FB_DTSG_REGEX = re.compile(r'"token":"(.*?)"')
```

Just add these lines of code on top of your file after importing everything.

Apparently using the header "User-Agent" in session has been breaking the code.
I retraced the error and found this solution, works for me.